# I want to create a new array using logstash input elasticsearch results

Tags: arrays, ruby, elasticsearch, logstash

I want to create a new array using logstash input elasticsearch results.

For example, the result is searched in the following query.

```
input {
 elasitcsearch{
  index => "test"
  query => "{'query':{'match':{'field1':'testtt'}},'_source':'field2'}"
 }
}
```

The result is shown below.

```
{
 'field2':1
}
{
 'field2':2
}
{
 'field2':3
}
```

Now I want to make the above objects into a new array.

like this...

`field2 = [1,2,3]`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use Logstash filter with aggregate plugin, something like:

```
filter {
  aggregate {
    task_id => "agregate_field2"
    code => "
      map['field2'] ||= []
      map['field2'] << event.get('field2')
      event.cancel()
    "
    push_previous_map_as_event => true
    timeout => 3
  }
}
```